# time series with 10 min frequency in R

Tags: r, time-series, timeserieschart

My data is memory consumption of an application for every 10 minute interval for the last 26 days.My start date is Oct 6th 2013 and end date is Novemeber 2nd 2013.I've read the data in to a time frame and cleaned it up. Now am trying to create a time series , something along the lines of   `my_ts<-ts(mydata[3],start=c(2013,10),frequency=10)`

Am sure this not correct as the frequency , can someone point me in the right direction so I can plot the time series
    .

Comment: Type `dput(head(your_data_frame))` and add the result to the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In R, `frequency` actually means the period of the seasonality. i.e., `frequency` = frequency of observations per season. In your case, the "season" is presumably one day. So you want

```
ts(mydata[3],start=c(2013,10),frequency=24*60/10)
```